TV (mini?) series from 80s or 90s set in Egypt, involves pyramids
I remember watching it as a kid (so 80s or 90s) on our national TV (Yugoslav then). Definitely a series, not a film feature. 
Cannot remember how many episodes but it had to do with the secrets of pyramids, which were sometimes revealed under the right angle of light falling inside them..? 
(At at least one instance in the series) it was a joint production (as you did at those times) with some Italian (Rai?) actors being dubbed - cannot be certain though, it's a bit unclear :) 
The main character is a strong, tanned, blonde man with a mustache, unshaven, as you would look if you spent a lot of time in the desert, wearing a white, I'll say turban, on his head. 
A secret order of riders (?) that protected the pyramids and/or their secrets but the main character not part of them originally (this could also be from The Mummy and/or a coincidence).
Not a lot to go on, I know, but the air of the show stuck with me and I wonder why :)
Any help much appreciated, thank you!

+1 for providing required details.

This could be the Tv mini-series "Secret of the Sahara", a.k.a "Il segreto del Sahara" (1988)
IMDb:

This seven episode RAI-1 TV-series production is about the quest of
  archaeologist Desmond Jordan to discover the location of the legendary
  Talking Mountain of the Sahara desert and find the secret that it
  hides.

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_of_the_Sahara
You can watch the complete series in one long, five-and-a-half hours long movie with Italian dubbing here:
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3cu78n
It is a TV mini-series, it was made at the end of the 80's, and was a European co-production (Italy, West Germany, Spain, etc.). Michael York is one of the main protagonists, he could be the blonde guy.
Michael York is the blonde protagonist:

And Michael York wearing the white turban:

And here is a shot of the secret order of riders, they are protecting the secret of the mountain (similar to Oded Fehr's bunch in the 1999 "The Mummy"), and they wear red headdress and robes:


oh, boy, that was quick and it looks like this could the one! thank you very much, you're a real buff ;)
funny enough, i couldn't recall michael york but i did remember the actor who plays an officer and the two kind of blended :D

will do! is there an english version, or one with subtitles??

I think there is a much shorter, heavily edited verson on Youtube, don't remember if it is in English.
